# Cannot use USB tethering on Linux, ethtool: autonegatiation not set ot enabled

Tags: linux, networking, usb, android, tethering

I am unable to use USB tethering with my android phone on my laptop.

I am using a Samsung Galaxy A8 Star Android 10 over USB cable to connect to my laptop running Kununtu 20.04LTS.

I have also tried using a Lenovo ZukZ1 android 5.1.1 but failed.

I have observed the following in the system logs when I enabled the tethering option on my phone...

```
16/05/21 10:28 PM   NetworkManager  <info>  [1621184297.8765] manager: (usb0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/44)
16/05/21 10:28 PM   kernel  rndis_host 1-3:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, RNDIS device, c2:54:7b:82:c6:1c
16/05/21 10:28 PM   mtp-probe   checking bus 1, device 54: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
16/05/21 10:28 PM   mtp-probe   bus: 1, device: 54 was not an MTP device
16/05/21 10:28 PM   systemd-udevd   Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
16/05/21 10:28 PM   systemd-udevd   ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
16/05/21 10:28 PM   mtp-probe   checking bus 1, device 54: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
16/05/21 10:28 PM   mtp-probe   bus: 1, device: 54 was not an MTP device
16/05/21 10:28 PM   ModemManager    <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3': not supported by any plugin
```

I tried easytether. That failed too... Any help would be very helpful.

Tethering is working fine on windows with the same phone and wire.

Thank you.

EDIT1:
[image: nmcli dev output]

[image: nmcli device show output]

Comment: Those logs seem normal; what does the new interface show up like in `nmcli dev`? Does it show up in the KDE networking settings?

Comment: No new interface is created...

Comment: That's weird, your log messages literally say that it is there (usb0).

Comment: If I try `ip link show `, I can see USB0 at the bottom set to DOWN.
If I try to set the interface to UP using the command `ip link set dev usb0 up`, the state changes to UNKNOWN.

Comment: Do you have data available on your phone plans?

Comment: Can you get the output of `NetworkManager --print-config`? Do things change in the device list if you do `nmcli dev set usb0 managed yes`?

Comment: @Burgi Yes, I have an active data plan
Thank you for inserting images